# Django CMS icon in menu

Tags: django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am trying to show my uploaded icon on navigation but i guess, i am going through a wrong way.

this is my model that extended

```
class IconExtension(PageExtension):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons')


extension_pool.register(IconExtension)
```

and this is my cms_toolbars.py file

```
@toolbar_pool.register
class IconExtensionToolbar(ExtensionToolbar):
    # defines the model for the current toolbar
    model = IconExtension

    def populate(self):
        # setup the extension toolbar with permissions and sanity checks
        current_page_menu = self._setup_extension_toolbar()

        # if it's all ok
        if current_page_menu:
            # retrieves the instance of the current extension (if any) and the toolbar item URL
            page_extension, url = self.get_page_extension_admin()
            if url:
                # adds a toolbar item in position 0 (at the top of the menu)
                current_page_menu.add_modal_item(_('Page Icon'), url=url,
                    disabled=not self.toolbar.edit_mode_active, position=0)
```

and this is my menu.html file

```
{% load menu_tags %}

{% for child in children %}
<li class="child{% if child.selected %} selected{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %} ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %} sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %} descendant{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}
    <img src="{{ child.image.url }}">
  </a>
    {% if child.children %}
    <ul>
        {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I am not getting why it is not working, I don't see any error even I don't see any image url here, my everything is working fine, only going through problem showing menu icon, can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just missing the reference to the object from the page, you're going straight to it's attribute.

I've got a very similar setup with images associated with pages;

```
class PageImage(PageExtension):
    """ Add images to pages """
    image = models.FileField(
        verbose_name=_("Image"),
        upload_to=upload_to('page_images')
    )
```

Which in my templates becomes;

```
{% if request.current_page.pageimage.image %}
    {{ request.current_page.pageimage.image.url }}
{% endif %}
```

So in your example, if you did this in a template you'd do;

```
{% if request.current_page.iconextension %}
    <img src="{{ request.current_page.iconextension.image.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Checking if the extension exists is important to avoid attribute errors etc.

In a menu, the `child` isn't a `Page` object though, it's a `NavigationNode` from the menu system. So it doesn't have your extension.

I think the proper solution to this is to setup a navigation `Modifier`. The docs for this are here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/menus.html#navigation-modifiers

Alternatively you could setup a template tag which you pass your `child` which could then use the `reverse_id` attribute to query the database for the `Page` that corresponds to, and return the `iconextension` of that page. I've used this method before.

Comment: It is working with request.current_page but not working with child.iconextension, I am not getting how to get it,

Comment: @howrecepes Oh, yeah good point. `child` in a menu template isn't a page, but a `NavigationNode` object. That makes things more complicated. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @markwalker_ answer. I did the job successfully in 3 Steps

**Step 1 - Add an FontAwesomeField in a page Extension :**
https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/extending_page_title.html

For the record here is my code :
In models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from cms.extensions import PageExtension
from cms.extensions.extension_pool import extension_pool


class IconExtension(PageExtension):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons', null=True, blank=True)
    fontawesomeicon = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)


extension_pool.register(IconExtension)
```

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.extensions import PageExtensionAdmin

from .models import IconExtension


class IconExtensionAdmin(PageExtensionAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(IconExtension, IconExtensionAdmin)
```

In cms_toolbars.py

```
from cms.toolbar_pool import toolbar_pool
from cms.extensions.toolbar import ExtensionToolbar
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .models import IconExtension


@toolbar_pool.register
class IconExtensionToolbar(ExtensionToolbar):
    # defines the model for the current toolbar
    model = IconExtension

    def populate(self):
        # setup the extension toolbar with permissions and sanity checks
        current_page_menu = self._setup_extension_toolbar()

        # if it's all ok
        if current_page_menu:
            # retrieves the instance of the current extension (if any) and the toolbar item URL
            page_extension, url = self.get_page_extension_admin()
            if url:
                # adds a toolbar item in position 0 (at the top of the menu)
                current_page_menu.add_modal_item(_('Page Icon'), url=url,
                    disabled=not self.toolbar.edit_mode_active, position=0)
```

**Step 2 - Implementing Navigation Modifier**
https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/menus.html#navigation-modifiers

In cms_menu.py

```
from menus.base import Modifier
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool

from cms.models import Page


class AddIconModifier(Modifier):
    """
    This modifier makes the changed_by attribute of a page
    accessible for the menu system.
    """

    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        if breadcrumb:
            return nodes
        # Only on last iteration (Voir : https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/menus.html#navigation-modifiers)
        if not post_cut:
            return nodes
        # only consider nodes that refer to cms pages
        # and put them in a dict for efficient access
        page_nodes = {n.id: n for n in nodes if n.attr["is_page"]}
        # retrieve the relevent pages
        pages = Page.objects.filter(id__in=page_nodes.keys())
        # loop over all relevant pages
        for page in pages:
            # take the node referring to the page            
            node = page_nodes[page.id]
            if hasattr(page, 'iconextension') and hasattr(page.iconextension ,'fontawesomeicon'):
                node.attr["faicon"] = page.iconextension.fontawesomeicon
            else:
                node.attr["faicon"] = 'fa-arrow-circle-right'
        
        return nodes


menu_pool.register_modifier(AddIconModifier)
```

**Step 3 - Specific navigation template**
In my main template :

```
{% show_menu 0 100 100 100 "partials/navigation.html" %}
```

In my navigation template (navigation.html)

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags cache %}

{% for child in children %}

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}"><i class="fas fa-fw {{ child.attr.faicon }}"></i>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        {% if child.children %}
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template '' '' child %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```